# Use single domain to host web application and aws api gatwway?

Tags: dns, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

Is it possible to configure dns settings in such way so web application is using www.domain.com and amazon aws api gateway uses www.domain.com/api?

Comment: What is your requirement? Could you instead use `api.domain.com` for API Gateway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using pure DNS, it would only let you point a subdomain to a destination, DNS doesn't see the path.

You can use something like nginx to proxy the path, or use `api.domain.com` for your API, which probably is better, as you don't need to proxy the requests at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure AWS CloudFront as a proxy to map both API Gateway and Web Server (Or web application hosted in AWS S3) as origins. Then configure 
www.domain.com to point to CloudFront.

This also improves the application performance, if you cache the static content, serving from the web application, by using the CloudFront CDN network of edge locations.

When mapping API Gateway do the following configuration for it to work.

- Whitelist the headers and exclude Host header.
- Set TTL values to zero.
- Make the origin and behaviors for API Gateway https only.
- To map www.domain.com/api to API Gateway, use the stage name as 'api' with CloudFront behavior mapping for /api/* .